# Acronym glossary doesn't appear

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, sharelatex

I'm trying to get an acronym glossary to appear on my ShareLaTeX project, but even the demo they have doesn't work:

https://www.sharelatex.com/project/554bfc42d1eab411203a5f23

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{gcd}{GCD}{Greatest Common Divisor}

\newacronym{lcm}{LCM}{Least Common Multiple}

\begin{document}
Given a set of numbers, there are elementary methods to compute 
its \acrlong{gcd}, which is abbreviated \acrshort{gcd}. This process 
is similar to that used for the \acrfull{lcm}.

\clearpage

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\end{document}
```

Gives me the paragraph of text on one page, then a blank second page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to run `Make Glossary`. Did you?

Comment: @HarishKumar can I explicitly run it in ShareLaTeX? I get normal glossaries, but no acronyms.

Answer (score 3):

It works for me when I use the alternative *noidx* commands for making and printing the glossary.

Replace

```
\makeglossaries
```

with

```
\makenoidxglossaries
```

and

```
\printglossary
```

with

```
\printnoidxglossary
```

This is refered to as *Option 1* for printing the glossary, in the manual.
Someone with more experience of the package can probably point out why your first approach does not work.

Comment: Thank you, just one additional note. Replacing `\printglossary` with `\printnoidxglossary[type=\acronymtype,numberedsection=autolabel]` worked for me, solution from the [ShareLaTeX Git](https://github.com/sharelatex/sharelatex-docker-image/issues/6) discussion page.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the [official documentation](https://it.sharelatex.com/learn/Glossaries) (unfortunately not very good highlighted):

> The acronyms list needs a temporary file generated by `\printglossary`
>   to work, thereby you must add said command right before the line
>   `\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]` and compile your document, once
>   you've compiled your document for the first time you can remove the
>   line `\printglossary`.

So if you put `\printglossary`, then compile, then comment out `\printglossary` and then compile again, it works.
Probably it works also before removing `\printglossary`, but I had to do this because if not, the `lhead` appeared also in the previous page of the list of acronyms.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.